# Can all OSS for Linux be built to run on an Illumos based OS like OpenIndiana?

Tags: linux, solaris, opensolaris, openindiana, illumos

I like trying different OSs, but I have yet to try a Illumos-based OS. Can I run all or most Linux Software, just by building from source?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to built most Linux software by hand (except very linux-kernel specific software), but as there are [Illumos-based distributions](http://wiki.illumos.org/display/illumos/Distributions) which include package manager, it should be way more easy to use them and install pre-built software packages from the corresponding repositories.
Using distributions with GNU userspace enhances also the compatibility with Linux/GNU system.

Building packages by hand can take very long and could require high system resources - if you are only trying some OSs, you normally do not want to do this.

Comment: I briefly played with [DilOS](http://www.dilos.org/) recently. It seems to work reasonably well. It uses the Debian `apt-get` package system. The main worry I have with any of these forks is longevity. Which are flashes in the pan, and which will prevail, if any?

Comment: For instance, the [pkgsrc](https://www.pkgsrc.org/) team statistics for their [most recent release in April 2015](http://mail-index.netbsd.org/pkgsrc-users/2015/04/14/msg021358.html) showed they successfully built 13092 out of 15246 packages in their collection for the SmartOS distro of illumos.

Comment: @alanc Do those statistics provide any indication of how much time and effort went into building each package on SmartOS?  In my experience, building Linux-developed packages on a Solaris-based OS often requires considerable effort.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - no they don't.  Making these packages build is part of Jonathan's job, and he's been increasing the number every quarter, so I would not be surprised if there's been many hours of effort to get that far.   I personally find that many of the more common & well maintained packages build out of the box, thanks to autoconf & similar tools, but I also maintain upstream software at X.Org and know it takes effort there to keep that working cross-platform.

Answer (score 3):

No; you can try to build the software, but it doesn't mean it'll be a success without source modifications. For example; building PHP 5.5 on OmniOS will fail at socket compatibility requiring patches to be a success; you can see my modifications [here](https://github.com/omniti-labs/omnios-build/commit/22132ac54d579556a24374df6a9635362494a354) to make it work.

Also, Linux based OS's are GNU; Illumos based ones are CDDL ([the leaders of illumos-gate based projects prefer CDDL over GNU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zRN7XLCRhc)); they do come with GNU software but it's not the default. You'll find that `grep -F` or certain `find` functionality doesn't work on Illumos OS's unless you use the `/usr/gnu/bin` version of the software.